# Extract follower numbers from Vkontakte using Python & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the follower count from a page on Vkontakte, a Russian social network. As I'm a complete beginner with Python, I have tried using a code I discovered on StackOverflow initially made to extract follower count on Twitter. Here's the original code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
username='realDonaldTrump'
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

f = soup.find('li', class_="ProfileNav-item--followers")
print(f)
```

I'm using this webpage as an example : https://vk.com/msk_my. Here is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://vk.com/msk_my'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
f = soup.find('span', class_="header_count fl_l")
print(f)
```

This, and many other variations I've tried (for example, trying to find "div" instead of "span", only prints "None". It seems BeautifulSoup can't find the follower count, and I'm sttruggling to understand why. The only way I've managed to print the follower count is with this :

```
text = soup.div.get_text()
print(text)
```

But this prints much more stuff than I want, and I don't know how to get only the follower count.

Comment: Twitter does not allow such parsing. Use twitter api to get whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will fetch you only the followers count. All you have to do is use selenium to be able to grab the exact page source that you can see by inspecting element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://vk.com/msk_my')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.quit()
item = soup.select(".header_count")[0].text
print("Followers: {}".format(item))
```

Result:

```
Followers: 59,343
```